# Convert an SSH URL to tramp filename

Tags: helm, tramp

When using the helm `find-file` replacement `helm-find-files`, SSH URL's are automatically converted to tramp filenames.  For example:

> ssh://john@example.com:/home/john

becomes

> /scp:john@example.com:/home/john/

Where does the logic for this string conversion reside?

Comment: Do you see the same thing with plain `find-file`, i.e., without Helm? If so, you can simplify the question. If not, maybe the logic resides in Helm. IOW, it might help to cut the investigation in half.

Comment: @Drew The behavior is *visibly* different with vanilla `find-file`.  The SSH URL remains as typed, but offers completions as if it were a proper tramp filename.  I think it's likely that these translations occur in different locations, so I mention only `helm-find-file` specifically to avoid confusion regarding the apparent behavior.

Comment: OK, thanks. Presumably that information may help someone help you. If you think so, you might want to include it in the question (comments can be deleted at any time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is implemented in `url-handlers.el`.

(From comment by @MichaelAlbinus:)

> `url-handlers.el` is a package implementing file name handlers for URLs. For the default methods, like https?, it uses the URL as it is. If a method belongs to one of the methods supported by Tramp (see `url-tramp-protocols` of `url-tramp.el`), it converts them to a Tramp file name via `url-tramp-convert-url-to-tramp`. So in fact, the proper answer to the question is `url-tramp.el`, because the conversion happens there.

Comment: That answers the question, but it might be helpful if you elaborated, e.g., by pointing to the particular code in the file that is responsible for the logic asked about.

Comment: url-handlers.el is a package implementing file name handlers for urls. For the default methods, like https?, it uses the url as it is. If a method belongs to one of the methods supported by Tramp (see `url-tramp-protocols` of url-tramp.el), it converts them to a Tramp file name via `url-tramp-convert-url-to-tramp`. So in fact, the proper answer to the question is url-tramp.el, because the conversion happens there.

Comment: OK; thx. I added that info to the answer itself. (Comments can be deleted at any time.)

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus Thanks for the information, but I don't think it is accurate in this case.  Notably, the `'url-tramp` feature isn't loaded following the string conversion during the interactive `helm-find-files` call.  Additionally, `url-tramp-convert-url-to-tramp` yields an `/ssh:` tramp filename for the sample string I mention-- compared to the `/scp:` that I observe with `helm-find-files`.

Comment: I cannot speak about helm, I don't use it.